# How to use tmux copy / paste in Termux?

Tags: termux

I installed Termux and using the pkg system installed tmux.

However, the tmux that installs doesn't appear to support copying and pasting.  I can enter copy mode, but I can't select text and copy it to the clipboard using the spacebar and the enter key.  Is there any way to go about this?

Comment: This wasn't a problem for me. I was able to paste using Command + Shift + V in and outside tmux. I pasted my clipboard which was taken from other apps (eg Chrome) and also my macOS, via `scrcpy`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try having this line in your `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
```

This enables a set of vi key bindings that seems to work fine. I used the Spacebar and Enter keys to copy that line from within a tmux session running in Termux and pasted it into this textbox in Chrome with Ctrl+v.

Comment: Yes that did work!  Nice work man.  I believe I used CTRL+B, started my cursor with the h, j, k, and L  keys pressed enter, and low and behold when I got to the address bar in Firefox I could paste it in!

Comment: Note, I may have used "+y as well....

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, tmux can't access Android system clipboard, unlike real GNU/Linux distros. The copy mode is pretty much isolated in tmux, so you can only copy from and paste to within sessions.

To paste from clipboard, long-press (hold) anywhere on the terminal screen and tap "Paste" in the pop-up menu.

To copy to clipboard, long-press some text on the terminal screen. Drag the pins to select the text you want to copy and tap "Copy" in the pop-up menu.

Comment: I was only trying to access it within the session and copy it between panes and windows.  Maybe I wasn't clear about that above.

Comment: if that's all you want to do, you can use files and redirect outputs accordingly.

Comment: One unfortunate thing about this is that the Termux pop-up menu pins don't know anything about vertically split panes, understandably, so that requires workarounds if you're trying to copy anything spanning multiple lines.

Comment: Correction: I meant it's a problem for text in *horizontally* split panes. I always get those terms mixed up. For some reason I keep wanting to think it refers to the orientation of the separator between the panes rather than the layout of the panes in relation to one another.

Comment: @JacobWan tmux's pane splitting is a good feature, but I don't think it works well on a phone's small screen, so I only use windows but not panes on my phone. For tablets, I admit copying text from splitted screen is a problem.

Answer (score 3):

This answer may be irrelevant to your needs, but I arrived at your post while trying to solve a problem. Unlike with the x windows system, you don't need anything but Termux to paste text. Use "share" on the selected text, share to Termux, then enter a filename as prompted, and tap open folder.

Answer (score 1):

In vim, go into input mode by pressing <kbd>i</kbd> and then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste.

Note: you can use specific keyboard apps or an external keyboard to gain access to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd> keys.

- Hacker's keyboard: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) / [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard/)
- AnysoftKeyboard: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard) / [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard/) (description at F-Droid broke, so don't let that fool you)

Comment: Could you please include instructions on how to press `crt-alt-V` on a smartphone software keyboard?

Comment: With a physical keyboard I use the ctrl alt v. For virtual keyboard I use gboards(or Samsung keyboard if im using my tab) builtin keyboard clipboard manager and tap the text card for what I want to paste.